# How to keep disabled the form against the default 'ng-model'

Tags: angularjs

I have a input field say `name`. i have added a `ng-model` in it with default value of 'Enter your Name'. but now the form submit button gets enabled. how to prevent the submit button enable from the default value?

here is my code :

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.field = {};

  $scope.field.name="Enter your Name"; //because of default value form enables.


});
```

HTML :

```
<form name="myForm">

      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="field.name" required>

      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>

    </form>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BqCjshgK64pUHDtO4Z4t?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `placeholder` instead of `name`. It has the intended effect without the above consequence.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="field.name" required>
```

Comment: I agree. But I am not able to color the placeholder text.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, you can use `color:red` to make it's text red.

Answer (score 0):

use this 'jugad'

```
 <button type="submit" ng-disabled="field.name=='Enter your Name'">Submit</button>
```

Comment: use this condition `ng-disabled="field.name=='Enter your Name'"`.

Comment: In case of sinlge field this is ok. in case of multiple input elements...!?. is there no way within the angularjs?

Comment: i think no way... use @The Laughing Man instructions